# Mocking a DateFormat class in junit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to Mock a DateFormat class, since it has no purpose in the scope of my unit test. I am using the org.mockito.Mockito library.

Following code:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.any;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import org.junit.Before;

public class someTest {

    @Mock
    DateFormat formatter; 

    @Before
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(formatter.format(any(Date.class))).thenReturn("2017-02-06");
    }
}
```

Gives following error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Invalid use of argument matchers! 3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
>
> -> at someTest.before(someTest.java:33)
>
> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>       //incorrect:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String"); When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers. For example:
>       //correct:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
>
> For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
>
> at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   someTest.before(someTest.java:33)

How do I mock the DateFormat class in a correct way?

Comment: Wouldn't it be just as easy to create a real instance? `formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("'2017-02-06'");`

Comment: @AndyTurner  What's the benefit of using a real instance compared to a Mocked object?

Comment: I'll flip that question around to you: what do you think you gain by mocking this object rather than using a real instance?

Comment: @AndyTurner Well - What if production code does NOT instantiate the DateFormat class through the SimpleDateFormat constructor. Then by your example we have a test that behaves differently than the code in production, which could lead to the case that errors occur in production and not in the unit test.

Comment: If the production code creates the instance in a certain way, then your mock will almost certainly do something different too, unless you set up the mock in excruciating detail to behave the same as the real class. And then... why not just use the real class?

Comment: @AndyTurner I dont agree with you. Instantiating the formatter through a constructor of SimpleDateFormat leads to a different code line and an instantiated object that differs from the instantiation of the object in production code. This we can agree upon. You were asking me what I gain by mocking this object. Well there's my answer.

Comment: A `SimpleDateFormat` *may* be a different implementation of `DateFormat` than the one used in production, but a mocked `DateFormat` is *definitely* a different implementation of `DateFormat` than the one used in production. Both *may* "leads to a different code".

Comment: And what's the benefit of using the real object? `formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("'2017-02-06'");` just works. No faffing about with Mockito's error message. No restrictions on not being able to mock final methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with implementation of `format(Date date)`

```
public final String format(Date date) {
    return format(date, new StringBuffer(),
                  DontCareFieldPosition.INSTANCE).toString();
}
```

As you can see, it's final. Mockito cannot mock final methods. Instead, it will call the real method.
As a workaround, you can mock method `format(date, new StringBuffer(), DontCareFieldPosition.INSTANCE)`

```
when(formatter.format(any(Date.class), any(StringBuffer.class), 
                      any(FieldPosition.class)))
    .thenReturn(new StringBuffer("2017-02-06"));
```

So when method `format(date)` will call your mocked method the result will be as you expected.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the cause of the error. The error message provided by the framework was imo a bit confusing. Your provided workaround is fine with me!

Comment: The slight detail that is missing here (or, perhaps, not made clear enough) is that the `when` call invokes the real method, which invokes the delegate method - so, the first that mockito knows about the `when` call is that the delegate method is invoked, so you have to configure the mock for *that* method call. This means that your test code is dependent on implementation details of `TextFormat` - so this makes the test code brittle, as a consequence of the [Fragile Base Class problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class).

Comment: @AndyTurner You mean DateFormat, not TextFormat, right? Otherwise I'm confused :) Yes, you are correct, changes in the mockit framework may cause the test to stop working, but that's fins with me. Updating tests are easily managed compared to production code. Good point, though!

Comment: @Henrik yes I mean `DateFormat`; but I am talking about fragility because of changes to that class, not mockito.

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh ok, so let me see if I get you right this time. You mean that if the Java sdk gets updated (which in my specific example would require a hands-on replacement of the Java version specified in build-files), then the static function in the DateFormat could change - leading to that this unit test doesn't cover the code line in production any more. Yes, that's a relevant point. But again, I think updating the Java version should always lead to updating relevant unit tests, and I would say this is normal behaviour in maintenance. The same problem exist with your answer as well.

Comment: @henrik no, my solution doesn't, and that's the point: the API of `DateFormat` is guaranteed, the implementation isn't.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, but your solution is dependent on SimpleDateFormat instead, and what happens if that constructor changes?

Comment: It can't: it's a public API. It is guaranteed not to change.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [Serghey Bishyr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42069319/3788176), you're trying to mock a [`final` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/text/DateFormat.java#343), which can't be done in Mockito.

If your mocking framework doesn't allow you to do something (like mocking a final method), you either have to find an alternative framework (like Powermock), or work around it in another way.

From the [Wikipedia article about mocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object#Reasons_for_use):

> In a unit test, mock objects can simulate the behavior of complex, real objects and are therefore useful when a real object is impractical or impossible to incorporate into a unit test. If an object has any of the following characteristics, it may be useful to use a mock object in its place:
>
> - the object supplies non-deterministic results (e.g. the current time or the current temperature);
> - it has states that are difficult to create or reproduce (e.g. a network error);
> - it is slow (e.g. a complete database, which would have to be initialized before the test);
> - it does not yet exist or may change behavior;
> - it would have to include information and methods exclusively for testing purposes (and not for its actual task).

None of the above points apply to your code, so there is no need to use a mock. And it's not "impractical or impossible" to use a real implementation of `DateFormat`.

Instead of supplying a mocked `DateFormat`, supply a `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("'2017-02-06'");
```

This will always return  `2017-02-06` for any input, as apparently desired from the code in the question, since `'`s cause the text between them to be taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the correct answers, one important note:

```
when(formatter.format(any(Date.class))
```

If the method wouldn't be final, you could just go with

```
when(formatter.format(any())
```

Mockito is clever enough to understand what comes and what goes out (at least when using Java8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerMock to do that.

in your app.gradle add this dependencies

```
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:${versions.powermock}"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:${versions.powermock}"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:${versions.powermock}"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:${versions.powermock}"
```

and then

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(android.text.format.DateFormat::class)
class YourTestClass {

@Before
fun setup() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(android.text.format.DateFormat::class.java)
    val format = SimpleDateFormat()
    format.applyPattern("dd/MM/y") //your format here
    PowerMockito.`when`(android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(any(Context::class.java))).thenAnswer {
        format
    }
}

... tests
```